# What does the final set of parentheses mean on this line?

Tags: c

What do the last set of parentheses on this line mean? The first set I know is a typecast, the second part (UiMsg) is a macro. What does (tseval) at the end do?

```
tempState = (ShowSelectState)UiMsg(tseval, current_index)(tseval);
```

Comment: Please give more information. Show at least the definition of the macro. Maybe try for a [mcve].

Comment: You could try to preprocess the a file with this line to see what the macro is doing. This is helpful if the macro is complicated.

Comment: `UIMsg()` probably evaluates to a function name, so `(tseval)` provides the arguments to that function call.

Comment: The macro is: `#define UiMsg(obj, member)       (obj)->msg->member`

Answer (score 2):

Since `UiMsg` is a function-like macro, the first set of parenthesis after it are the arguments to the macro.  So you first need to perform the macro substitution to see what is happening.

So this:

```
tempState = (ShowSelectState)UiMsg(tseval, current_index)(tseval);
```

Becomes:

```
tempState = (ShowSelectState)(tseval)->msg->current_index(tseval);
```

Now we can see that the second set of parenthesis denotes the arguments of the `current_index` member, which presumably is a function pointer.